# Visual Studio Code beginners issue with img not showing

Tags: html, css, image, bootstrap-5

Am just a beginner in all aspects and am stuck with an issue I created with an image showing as[screenshot of mess made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95TfU.png) a placemat in Visual Studio Code.
The code I put in is line 25: `<img src="sml flower nb.png" alt="flower">`
I believe I tied myself in knots is I tried to create an image folder, but ended up creating a cascade down of sub folders and each time I tried to rectify my mistake, I just made it worse.
I have no idea what to do next to just get the pathway right for a simple image that has been put into a folder (not a url.)
Can anyone assist and show me how to resolve the issue?
TIA
R

Tried to create img folder, but ended up with sub folders and cascades down whilst trying to rectify.

Answer (score -1):

```
<img src="sml flower nb.png" alt="flower">
```

Id rename the file to smlflowernb.png because spaces tend to break things but it should work as long as the html file and image are in the same directory if you want to make a directory and point it to the image in that dir `<img src="images/flower.png" alt="Flower Image">` something like that but your file names ofc in this case the subdir /images has the image make sure that your html code is one above so /html-code/images so it can acsess the dir hope you get that!

Comment: Thanks so much for answering - can I just clarify with the second part of your answer; so if I have a subdirectory, lets say 'library, so first the html.index file should be above and then the code should read library/flower.png.....?
I am going to copy all my html code into notepad++, delete all the mess of files and folders I created and then start again with clean folders and re-input the code. fingers crossed. Many thanks for your advice and will update, once have tried to resolve.